# yum update version issue

Tags: fedora, yum

I am using fedora 13 (2.6.33 ). Due to some reasons I cannot update the kernel nor can I upgrade fedora itself to 18 due to some legacy software I am using for business purpose. So my question is how do I update my applications to the latest versions using yum without actually updating the kernel/distro. For eg when I

```
yum update firefox
```

It shows me the firefox version 3.x. instead of 19.0.

I have the option to download the binaries from website but for some applications I manually have to resolve the dependency issue.

So how do I temporarily set my source to fedora 18 source for some specific application.

Comment: Fedora 13 is End Of Life. And you can't upgrade from 13 to 18. A freshly install is recommended.

Comment: plz re read the question. My core business software is made for that specific kernel version. distro update is completely out of question

Comment: I'm afraid you need to build such applications by yourself. You can't use the repositories of fedora 18 to update your *specific* fedora 13 applications, because rpm(s) built for fedora 18 will introduce the dependency of fedora 18 system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that you can run latest Firefox on that prehistoric system. And I'd *strongly* advise against exposing it to the Internet, there are all sort of problems with that system, that won't ever be fixed. Isolate the machine as much as possible, and start considering alternatives (operating system, better something enterprisey like [CentOS](http://www.centos.org); and also the application, something that hasn't been updated in that many years and can't be rebuilt is not something I'd bet my livelihood on).

Answer (score 1):

Use a VM instance to run the legacy software, do everything else in the real world.

Comment: Yes thats a valid option but VM imposes some hardware restrictions and software inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you cannot directly upgrade from Fedora 13 to Fedora 18. Your best bet it to make a fresh install of Fedora 18.

However, if you still want to go the upgrade route, there's a package called **preupgrade** in Fedora 13. Using this you can upgrade to Fedora 17. PLease check Fedora's documentation mentioned [here for detailed instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_PreUpgrade?rd=PreUpgrade).

Once you have upgraded to Fedora 17, you can upgrade to Fedora 18 using [FedUp](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp). FedUp is PreUpgrade's replacement from Fedora 18 onwards and The FedUp client does not build or run on anything older than Fedora 17. If you want to upgrade an older Fedora installation, you have to upgrade to Fedora 17 before continuing.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am not allowed to upgrade to the latest version of fedora due to some legacy software I am using for business purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult constellation. Perhaps you could build a chroot-environment for your application that includes all that is needs?

Is this a classical executable or a java-based application?

Anyway you have to take special security precautions for such a system (inbound AND outbound strict firewalls, HIDS, ...). Installing firefox locally is not a good solution - as firefox has lots of security problems itselv.